# The derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus

How would one interpret:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^x (F(y)-F(x))\,\mathrm dy$$
I don't think I can use the fundamental theorem of calculus here, can I?

Comment: For this problem you need that $F$ is a differentiable function. If it is, then indeed the fundamental theorem of calculus comes up here, but it's not immediate. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Ragib:  F is differentiable.  But then I just get F(x)-F(x) = 0 which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Ragib:  Ok, Mathematica is giving me -x *F'(x) as the answer.  but I can't figure out why exactly!

Comment: See J.M's answer on the correct way to evaluate it. Your error lies in the fact that your integrand depends on $x$.

Comment: @Ragib:  I think i get what it's going -- taking the derivative  of the integrand wrt x, then integrating over 0 to x.  But where does the fundamental theorem fit in?  Even though dy = dx, I can't just swap one for another?

Comment: Angada, the fundamental theorem applies at the time you evaluate $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_0^x F(y)\mathrm dy$... the $y$ is a *dummy*; it could've been a $t$ and what I did still applies.

Comment: That's not exactly what J.M. did. The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f$ is differentiable, then $ \frac{d}{dx}\int^x_a f(t) dt = f(x) $. Note that the integrand $f(t)$ does not depend on the upper limit of integration, $x$. So to be able to use FTC, J.M. first had to remove the $F(x)$ term out of the integral. Note also that $F(x)$ is held as a constant whilst integrating with respect to $y$.

Comment: @Ragib -- I actually wrote my last comment before I saw JM's answer.  But, I still wouldn't have gotten it, so this is very helpful!!  Thanks!

Comment: Angada: as a tiny piece of advice, next time please **don't** accept answers until you have truly understood them, and are completely satisfied by them. :)

Comment: @J.M.  -- I thought I understood.  I followed what you were doing well enough to answer the question, I just didn't see the link with the FTC.  Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: No problem. I'm just telling you that the check mark is an important piece of feedback, IMHO. If you aren't sure/satisfied with an answer you've gotten, it is perfectly acceptable to hold off accepting an answer...

Comment: @J.M.  Thanks for the feedback.  I suppose I am a little quick on accepting in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly doable:

$$\begin{split}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^x (F(y)-F(x))\,\mathrm dy&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_0^x F(y)\mathrm dy-F(x)\int_0^x \,\mathrm dy\right)\\&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_0^x F(y)\mathrm dy-x\,F(x)\right)\\&=F(x)-x\,F^\prime(x)-F(x)\\&=-x\,F^\prime (x)\end{split}$$

Comment: In the general case, it intuitively ought to hold (under appropriate assumptions) that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(x,y)dy=\int_0^x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dy + f(x,x)$$ which agrees with this solution for the case where $f$ can be separated into terms depending only on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm under what conditions it is going to hold? I am solving a similar problem, but the bounds of integration are $(-\infty, \infty)$